# How/What is the best way to auto create/save text file version of automated test reporter logs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js, webdriver-io

It's my first time building proper selenium tests (I've touched on IDE before). I'm using Selenium with NodeJS, WebdriverIO, Mocha framework, wdio-spec-reporter and wdio-browserstack-service.
I have managed to create my tests, suites specified in conf.js , hooked into browserstack (so when i run in command line, it creates a text log and video in browserstack).
Now I've been asked to do something so that when a test/suite is run it will automatically save the text logs as a text file.

My thoughts are either building an additional function and hooking into the spec reporter or retrieving them from browserstack. I've spent a bit of time googling it, but apart from using the allure reporter (looks like it can do this?), I am struggling to find any information. Is this possible? If so, how & which way?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out. The reporter was using the globally built reporter.js file (in AppData folder), not the one inside the plugin folder. All I needed was to print the results just before the *"return output;"* statement. Looking something like;

```
var d = new Date();
var fileDate = (d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate()+'-'+d.getFullYear()+'_'+(d.getHours()+1)+'-'+d.getMinutes()+'-'+d.getSeconds();
var fileName = 'test-log_'+fileDate+'.txt';
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(fileName, output, function (err) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that previous solution was a good practice because of changing the webdriverio itself. Now I'm using **json-reporter** which makes parsing information very easy and logs everything needed